# Why even i am instantiating template parameter at runtime but i am getting expected output instead of error ie. we cannot expand template at runtime?

Tags: c++, templates

As I know that templates are expanded at compile time but in below example i am deciding or doing
template instantiation at runtime depending on user input but still i am getting expected output.how this running?
can someone explain me

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Demo
{
   T Value = 20.67;
   public:
    void print(T val)
    {
        std::cout << "value :" << val << std::endl;
    }

    T getValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }

};

int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "Enter value for a :";
    std::cin >> a;
    if(a == 10)
    {
       Demo<int> demoObj1;
       demoObj1.print(demoObj1.getValue());
    }
    else
    {
       Demo<float> demoObj2;
       demoObj2.print(demoObj2.getValue());
    }
}
```

> //output:
>
> > > Enter value for a :10
> > > value :20
> > >
> > > and   Enter value for a :7
> > > value :20.67

Comment: Both `Demo<int>` and `Demo<float>` will be instantiated compile time as you're using a normal(non-constexpr) if, else instead of `constexpr if`.

Comment: You may be confusing "template instantiation" with "class instantiation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, both templates are created. There exists code in your compiled program for both branches. At runtime you are simply selecting which branch to execute.

The compiler sees the two branches of code and realizes that it cannot determine which branch will be taken at compile time, so it will generate code for both branches. If the compiler can determine at compile time that a branch cannot possibly be taken, a compiler may optimize it away. A simple situation is with the following:

```
if (4 < 5) {
   Demo<int> demoObj1;
   demoObj1.print(demoObj1.getValue());
} else {
   Demo<float> demoObj2;
   demoObj2.print(demoObj2.getValue());
}
```

In this case, the compiler can see that the second branch will never get executed. The compiler will initially compile both branches, but then it may discard the second branch from the final executable. Whether or not the compiler does this depends on the compiler implementation and compilation flags.

You can force the compiler to reject unused branches with `if constexpr`. Consider the following example:

```
if constexpr (4 < 5) {
   Demo<int> demoObj1;
   demoObj1.print(demoObj1.getValue());
} else {
   Demo<float> demoObj2;
   demoObj2.print(demoObj2.getValue());
}
```

All that was changed is that this example uses `if constexpr`. In this example, the second branch will NOT be fully compiled (it is still checked for correct syntax, but assembly generation is not done). Code for the second branch will not exist in the executable.

Comment: But how compiler without taking user input creating both templates defination at compile time only?

Comment: The compiler doesn't need runtime information to figure this out. It can see that you are writing code for both `Demo<int>` and `Demo<float>` and so it compiles both of them. If you added a `Demo<double>` anywhere in the code, the compiler would know to generate code for that as well.

Comment: It might be interesting to paste this code into Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/) and see the generated assembly code. You can see separate assembly for each template instantiation.

Comment: you mean whereever compiler find Demo<int> or Demo<float> or Demo<*>, then compiler will add template defination for it without thinking whether any preconditions for that satisfied or not

Comment: Yes. Runtime preconditions aren't going to effect the generated code - the compiler has to generate code regardless because it doesn't know which path will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Demo<int>` and `Demo<float>` will be instantiated compile time as you're using a normal(non-constexpr) if, else instead of `constexpr if`.

On the other hand, if you were to use `constexpr if` then only one of `Demo<int>` or `Demo<float>` would've been instantiated. Note that in this example we can't use `constexpr if` since the input is taken from user.

Comment: This example couldn't use `if constexpr` because the branch depends on a runtime parameter.

Comment: @DeanJohnson Yes, i've mentioned that at the end of my answer since here input is taken from user.

Comment: If i am using constexpr then my compilation is failing because we are taking input from the user at runtime and constexpr is expecting input at compile time.Right?

Comment: @Mangy It fails because `a` is not a constant expression. If you were to make `a`  compile time constant, the program will work. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b3Tnebq5x)